# NSStoreModelVersionHashes Bug in Core-Data Migration

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am having an issue with Core-Data light-weight migration at the moment. After digging around, I found out that there is an issue with NSStoreModelVersionHashes on one of the entities in my model. This actually happened even before I added a model version to my Core-Data model and I verified this by recreating the model.

I obtained the version hash values of my model programmatically using the following two methods:

```
    NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath] error:&error];
    NSDictionary *hashesFromMetadata = [sourceMetadata objectForKey:@"NSStoreModelVersionHashes"];
```

and

```
    NSMutableArray *filePaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *directoryPath = [bundle pathForResource:modelName ofType:@"momd"];        
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath];

    NSString *filePath;
    while ((filePath = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil){
        if([[filePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mom"]) {
            [filePaths addObject:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath]];    
        } 
    }
    /* Model.momd directory contains only one "mom" file: Model.mom" */
    NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[filePaths objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];
    NSDictionary *hashesFromModel = [model entityVersionHashesByName];
```

To my surprise, I found that I have two different hash values. Note that I have not added any model version yet and I have not modified the model at all. See the hash values of EntityB below.

```
    hashesFromMetadata: {
        EntityA = "8fc59055 bd81d862 198a4cf8 160ab711 84191bd4 2340eb4b 1ceeb19b 4643f7d6";
        EntityB = "bf73667d 19a25289 cd013e23 fc4524ce fb1095f9 6ad13aec f978ae1a 321388ed";
        EntityC = "4a55d875 fdb54969 c56d7add 201cb2c3 e244a5f1 b4950a74 55af1372 fa4f79b8";
        EntityD = "60fe2d8c e0061e78 c43f10aa 58cf1b5e 4cbb52a3 351ac83f 144ade9d 8687b22b";
        EntityE = "75c68768 31ef472b 567df030 36f99100 f52aa84e 7c8e2e81 1d070f07 cfd922be";
        EntityF = "53823f0a 94745434 d9076b5c c8f8b153 b74a2f9c 06f15576 e5878527 d1309d4f";
    }

    hashesFromModel: {
        EntityA = "8fc59055 bd81d862 198a4cf8 160ab711 84191bd4 2340eb4b 1ceeb19b 4643f7d6";
        EntityB = "c671f2ef 52eb91b1 73e4e9f2 92b70eed 9b09da23 ef66c016 4d684047 9d7b1efe";
        EntityC = "4a55d875 fdb54969 c56d7add 201cb2c3 e244a5f1 b4950a74 55af1372 fa4f79b8";
        EntityD = "60fe2d8c e0061e78 c43f10aa 58cf1b5e 4cbb52a3 351ac83f 144ade9d 8687b22b";
        EntityE = "75c68768 31ef472b 567df030 36f99100 f52aa84e 7c8e2e81 1d070f07 cfd922be";
        EntityF = "53823f0a 94745434 d9076b5c c8f8b153 b74a2f9c 06f15576 e5878527 d1309d4f";
    }
```

I also inspected the contents of VersionInfo.plist file and I found that the hash values are identical to the ones in hashesFromModel.

Obviously, this difference will always cause Core-Data migration to fail with an error: "Cannot find model for source store".

Has anyone come across this problem before? Any idea how to perform a lightweight migration in this case? Your input/feedback is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.